# Detectar error de Variable en SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bueno tengo el siguiente Insert:

```
INSERT INTO [PS_GameData].[dbo].[Chars] 
([ServerID], [UserID], [UserUID], [CharName], [New], [Del], [Slot], 
[Family], [Grow], [Hair], [Face], [Size], [Job], [Sex], [Level], 
[StatPoint], [SkillPoint], [Str], [Dex], [Rec], [Int], [Luc], [Wis], 
[HP], [MP], [SP], [Map], [Dir], [Exp], [Money], [PosX], [PosY], [Posz], 
[Hg], [Vg], [Cg], [Og], [Ig], [K1], [K2], [K3], [K4], [KillLevel], 
[DeadLevel], [RegDate], [DeleteDate], [JoinDate], [LeaveDate], 
[RenameCnt], [OldCharName], [RemainTime], [Staff], [LoginStatus], [GS], 
[GM], [Faction], [Pagado_1], [Pagado_2], [Pagado_3], [Pagado_4], 
[Pagado_5], [Pagado_6], [Pagado_7], [Pagado_8], [Pagado_9], [Pagado_10], 
[Pagado_11], [Pagado_12]) 
VALUES ('1', 'jocker1', '2394', '[ADM]Dificil', '1', '1', '0', '3', '2', 
'0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '60', '98', '999', '30', '12', '11', '8', '11', 
'7', '-20725', '-25106', '-24403', '42', '17', '11725422', '56396', 
'43,9692', '-0,4', '42,50782', '0', '200', '0', '0', '0', '12', '0', '0', 
'0', '0', '0', '2018-05-28 02:28:04.403', '2018-07-15 16:41:09.257', 
'2018-07-15 11:40:25.737', '2018-07-13 20:18:14.453', '0', NULL, 
'1239342308', NULL, N'0         ', NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', '0', '0', '0', 
'0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
```

Cuya estruptura de Tabla es :

```
USE [PS_GameData]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Chars]    Script Date: 08/04/2018 14:14:49 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chars](
    [ServerID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [UserUID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CharID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CharName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [New] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Del] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Slot] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Family] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Grow] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Hair] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Face] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Job] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Sex] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Level] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [StatPoint] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SkillPoint] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Str] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Dex] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Rec] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Int] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Luc] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Wis] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [HP] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [MP] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SP] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Map] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Dir] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Exp] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Money] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PosX] [real] NOT NULL,
    [PosY] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Posz] [real] NOT NULL,
    [Hg] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Vg] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Cg] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Og] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Ig] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [K1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [K2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [K3] [int] NOT NULL,
    [K4] [int] NOT NULL,
    [KillLevel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DeadLevel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [RegDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeleteDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [JoinDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LeaveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RenameCnt] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [OldCharName] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [RemainTime] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Staff] [smallint] NULL,
    [LoginStatus] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [GS] [int] NULL,
    [GM] [int] NULL,
    [Faction] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_1] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_2] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_3] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_4] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_5] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_6] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_7] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_8] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_9] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_10] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_11] [int] NULL,
    [Pagado_12] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Chars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CharID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_New]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [New]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_Del]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Del]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_level]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Level]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_StatPoint]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [StatPoint]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_SkillPoint]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SkillPoint]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_map]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Map]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_dir]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Dir]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_exp]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Exp]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_money]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Money]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_posx]  DEFAULT ((674.442)) FOR [PosX]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_posy]  DEFAULT ((3.640)) FOR [PosY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_posz]  DEFAULT ((1000.924)) FOR [Posz]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_K1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [K1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_K2]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [K2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_K3]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [K3]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_K4]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [K4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_KillLevel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [KillLevel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_DeadLevel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DeadLevel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_RegDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RegDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Chars_RemainTime]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [RemainTime]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_3]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_5]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_6]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_7]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_8]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_9]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_10]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_11]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Chars] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Pagado_12]
GO
```

Mi problema que al ejecutar la consulta me sale el siguiente error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>       Error converting data type varchar to real.

Yo se que la `PosX,PosY,PosZ` son valores `(Real)` segun leo me dice debe estar un `trigger` o `procedure` que tiene el `PosX,PosY,PosZ` como valor (`Varchar`) y la tabla no tiene disparadores (`TRIGGERS`) mientras que `procedures` (PROCEDIMIENTOS ALMACENADOS) tiene MILES, Según se lee el error NO DICE QUE `PROCEDURE` tiene el error. Mi pregunta es

**¿COMO puedo detectar dicho error en la DB para cambiar este a su valor (real) que este deberia de tener?**

Answer (score 1):

El insert que pones de ejemplo tiene todo los valores de tipo VARCHAR(fijate las comillas en los valores numéricos por ejemplo '0' en lugar de 0). Esto hace que cuando tratas de insertar un valor VARCHAR en un campo definido como REAL se realice una operación de CAST implícita.

Esta operación rechaza los valores con coma del tipo 'x,x' teniendo que poner los valores decimales utilizando el punto 'x.x'

Prueba de cambiar los valores con coma:

```
'43,9692', '-0,4', '42,50782'
```

Por puntos

```
'43.9692', '-0.4', '42.50782'
```

Y debería funcionar.
También puedes usar la función

```
REPLACE('43.9692', ',', '.')
```

en caso de que ya te llegue la variable varchar.

**Nota**: Si utilizas SQL Server 2012 en adelante cuentas con la instrucción PARSE que te permite indicar el idioma y hacerlo más fácil (Ver ejemplo aquí https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) pero bueno, como el título dice en un 2008 R2, no hay otra que las mencionadas.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta,
Saludos